# Vim encryption and rebasing

Tags: git, encryption, vim, rebase

I was rebasing some of my old git commits to squash them into a new commit, but I'm new to Vim and accidentally set an encryption key while in the middle of the rebase. Since Vim encryption is normally used for files, what happens to the encryption key I set in the middle of the rebase? Did I encrypt the rebase and will this affect any of my files or commits? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use vim's encryption, but per the docs it just acts on the file's data at read and write time based on the key set in the one vim session. If you quit the vim session you lose the key. If you set the key to empty and write out the file you'll write out the file unencrypted. All of this internal stuff in vim is invisible to Git; Git sees only the file contents.

Comment: Thanks for your help torek!